# Could not compute QR decomposition of Hessian CFA/SEM

Tags: r, structural-equation-model

I am using the sem package to build a SEM model. The model can be run however, there is a warning message like this:

```
Warning message:
In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
Could not compute QR decomposition of Hessian.
Optimization probably did not converge.
```

If I run summary(cfa1.test), the warning error message is like this:

```
Error in summary.objectiveML(cfa1.test) : 
coefficient covariances cannot be computed
In addition: Warning message:
In vcov.sem(object, robust = robust, analytic = analytic.se) :
singular Hessian: model is probably underidentified.
```

My model is about the relationships among Market Orientation (MO), Government Incentives(GvIncent), Entreprenuerial Orientation(EO) and Firm Performance(FirmP). These are the four second order constructs. Under each of them there are a number of constructs, for example, Responsiveness (Resp), Proactiveness (Proa), Economic Performance(EconP), Government Financial Incentives (GvFin) and under those sub constructs, there are observed variables such as Resp3,4, 5 and EconP(1-12).

Below are the codes of my model:

```
model.1<-specifyModel()
 GvInfo->GvInfo1, NA, 1       #all the lamda observed to latent (56 lines)
 GvInfo->GvInfo2, lam112, NA
 GvInfo->GvInfo3, lam113, NA
 GvInfo->GvInfo4, lam114, NA
 GvInfo->GvInfo5, lam115, NA
 GvInfo->GvInfo6, lam116, NA
 GvInfo->GvInfo7, lam117, NA
 GvFin->GvFin1, NA, 1
 GvFin->GvFin2, lam122, NA
 GvFin->GvFin3, lam123, NA
 GvFin->GvFin4, lam124, NA
 GvFin->GvFin5, lam125, NA
 GvFin->GvFin6, lam126, NA
 GvFin->GvFin7, lam127, NA
 GvPat->GvPat1, NA, 1
 GvPat->GvPat2, lam132, NA
 GvPat->GvPat3, lam133, NA
 GvPat->GvPat4, lam134, NA
 GvPat->GvPat5, lam135, NA
 EconP->EconP1, NA, 1
 EconP->EconP2, lam402, NA
 EconP->EconP3, lam403, NA
 EconP->EconP4, lam404, NA
 EconP->EconP5, lam405, NA
 EconP->EconP6, lam406, NA
 EconP->EconP7, lam407, NA
 EconP->EconP8, lam408, NA
 EconP->EconP9, lam409, NA
 EconP->EconP10, lam410, NA
 EconP->EconP11, lam411, NA
 EconP->EconP12, lam412, NA
 SocP->SocP1, NA, 1
 SocP->SocP2, lam422, NA
 InfoG->InfoG1, NA, 1
 InfoG->InfoG2, lam312, NA
 InfoG->InfoG3, lam313, NA
 InfoG->InfoG4, lam314, NA
 InfoG->InfoG5, lam315, NA
 InfoG->InfoG6, lam316, NA
 InfoD->InfoD1, NA, 1
 InfoD->InfoD2, lam322, NA
 InfoD->InfoD3, lam323, NA
 InfoD->InfoD4, lam324, NA
 InfoD->InfoD5, lam325, NA
 Resp->Resp3, NA, 1
 Resp->Resp4, lam334, NA
 Resp->Resp5, lam335, NA
 Innov->Innov1, NA, 1
 Innov->Innov2, lam212, NA
 Innov->Innov3, lam213, NA
 Proa->Proa1, NA, 1
 Proa->Proa2, lam222, NA
 Proa->Proa3, lam223, NA
 RiskT->RiskT1, NA, 1
 RiskT->RiskT2, lam232, NA
 RiskT->RiskT3, lam233, NA  #all the lamda observed to latent

GvIncent->GvInfo, NA, 1 #sub construct to construct (11 lines)
 GvIncent->GvFin, beta12, NA
 GvIncent->GvPat, beta13, NA
 FirmP->EnoP, NA, 1
 FirmP->SocP, beta42, NA
 EO->Innov, NA, 1
 EO->Proa, beta22, NA
 EO->RiskT, beta23, NA
 MO->InfoG, NA, 1
 MO->InfoD, beta32, NA
 MO->Resp, beta33, NA #sub construct to construct

EO->FirmP, beta24, NA #path from end to end constructs (5 lines)
 MO->FirmP, beta34, NA #path from end to end constructs
 GvIncent->EO, gam12, NA #exd to end construct
 GvIncent->FirmP, gam14, NA #exd to end construct
 EO<->MO, psi23, NA #correlation btw end
 GvIncent<->GvIncent, phi11, NA #error temrs for exds (4 lines)
 EO<->EO, psi22, NA #error temrs for ends
 MO<->MO, psi33, NA 
 FirmP<->FirmP, psi44, NA #error temrs for ends
 GvInfo<->GvInfo, psi1111, NA #error temrs for ends subconstructs (11 lines)
 GvFin<->GvFin, psi1212, NA
 GvPat<->GvPat, psi1313, NA
 Innov<->Innov, psi2121, NA
 Proa<->Proa, psi2222, NA
 RiskT<->RiskT, psi2323, NA
 InfoG<->InfoG, psi3131, NA
 InfoD<->InfoD, psi3232, NA
 Resp<->Resp, psi3333, NA #error terms for ends subconstructs
 EconP<->EconP, psi4141, NA
 SocP<->SocP, psi4242, NA
 GvInfo1<->GvInfo1, the111, NA          #errors of the factor indicators of ends
 GvInfo2<->GvInfo2, the112, NA
 GvInfo3<->GvInfo3, the113, NA
 GvInfo4<->GvInfo4, the114, NA
 GvInfo5<->GvInfo5, the115, NA
 GvInfo6<->GvInfo6, the116, NA
 GvInfo7<->GvInfo7, the117, NA
 GvFin1<->GvFin1, the121, NA
 GvFin2<->GvFin2, the122, NA
 GvFin3<->GvFin3, the123, NA
 GvFin4<->GvFin4, the124, NA
 GvFin5<->GvFin5, the125, NA
 GvFin6<->GvFin6, the126, NA
 GvFin7<->GvFin7, the127, NA
 GvPat1<->GvPat1, the131, NA
 GvPat2<->GvPat2, the132, NA
 GvPat3<->GvPat3, the133, NA
 GvPat4<->GvPat4, the134, NA
 GvPat5<->GvPat5, the135, NA   
 EconP1<->EconP1, the401, NA
 EconP2<->EconP2, the402, NA
 EconP3<->EconP3, the403, NA      
 EconP4<->EconP4, the404, NA
 EconP5<->EconP5, the405, NA
 EconP6<->EconP6, the406, NA
 EconP7<->EconP7, the407, NA
 EconP8<->EconP8, the408, NA
 EconP9<->EconP9, the409, NA
 EconP10<->EconP10, the410, NA
 EconP11<->EconP11, the411, NA
 EconP12<->EconP12, the412, NA
 SocP1<->SocP1, the421, NA
 SocP2<->SocP2, the422, NA
 InfoG1<->InfoG1, the311, NA
 InfoG2<->InfoG2, the312, NA
 InfoG3<->InfoG3, the313, NA
 InfoG4<->InfoG4, the314, NA
 InfoG5<->InfoG5, the315, NA
 InfoG6<->InfoG6, the316, NA
 InfoD1<->InfoD1, the321, NA
 InfoD2<->InfoD2, the322, NA
 InfoD3<->InfoD3, the323, NA
 InfoD4<->InfoD4, the324, NA
 InfoD5<->InfoD5, the325, NA
 Resp3<->Resp3, the333, NA
 Resp4<->Resp4, the334, NA
 Resp5<->Resp5, the335, NA
 Innov1<->Innov1, the211, NA
 Innov2<->Innov2, the212, NA
 Innov3<->Innov3, the213, NA
 Proa1<->Proa1, the221, NA
 Proa2<->Proa2, the222, NA
 Proa3<->Proa3, the223, NA
 RiskT1<->RiskT1, the231, NA
 RiskT2<->RiskT2, the232, NA
 RiskT3<->RiskT3, the233, NA           #errors of the factor indicators of ends
 #model1 test
 cfa1.test<-sem(model.1,cormat.model.1, N=534)
 summary(cfa1.test)
```

It would be nice if anyone could let me know what probelms do the error and warning messages indicate and how should I deal with them.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.